# Swift 4: Decodable null container

Tags: swift, decodable

I'm currently learning swift and i'm trying to make a api call that can send two different responses:

First one is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1
},
    "error": null
}
```

Second one is:

```
{
    "data": null,
    "error": " Password not matching"
}
```

So in the first json the data is a nested container, and in the second one its not.

What i have so far is the following, which works fine for the first case, but i have no idea how to change my struct to handle the second case. Any hits/ideas would be greatly appreciated:

```
struct ApiData {
    let userID: Int?
    let error: String?
}

extension ApiData: Decodable{

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data = "data"
        case userId = "id"
        case error = "error"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        do {
            let data = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .data)
            let userId = try data.decode(Int.self, forKey: .userId)
            self.init(userID: nil, error: nil)
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

If i try in the do block to decode the error case, when received the first type of response, will get a "Data is not in the correct format error" thrown.

Comment: data should be its own struct with a `id` property and then the data struct is a property in `ApiData`

Answer (score 1):

`data` is object which can be nil. You're missing optional property for `data` and `userId` (`id`) should be property of `data`.

```
struct ApiData: Decodable {
    let data: DataObject?
    let error: String?
}
```

Also you don't have struct for `data`

```
struct DataObject: Decodable {
    let userId: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userId = "id"
    }
}
```

**Notes:** you don't have to use `CodingKeys` for `ApiData`, just for `DataObject`

Comment: Thank you, this worked and got me a better picture of how to use Decodable. I don't understand what you mean by that note though. What should i change to a variable? I've currently reworked it like this: extension DataObject{
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        
       let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
       let userId = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .userId)
       self.init(userId: userId)
    }
}

Comment: @CodeGeass yes, you're right, you don't have to use it.

Comment: @CodeGeass but look, when you're using `CodingKeys`, you don't have to have init with decoder. All you need are just `CodingKeys`

Comment: @Sh_Khan but better would be if he had same struct format as his JSON.